# How can I animate simple shapes with java?

Tags: java, animation, user-interface

Any suggestions on how to get a shape moving. I have various sized ellipses in different directions (as i wanted) printed out on a jFRAME however they are not moving (i.e animated)...Any suggestions on how I can get them moving?

Comment: How is this different  to your [moving shapes with java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415500/moving-shapes-with-java) question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom component capable of painting your shapes, say something like a `JPanel`.  Override it's `paintComponent` method and draw all the shapes as required.

Use something like a `javax.swing.Timer`, set it to repeat about every 40 milliseconds (25fps).

When it "ticks", update the movement requirements of all the shapes and call `repaint` on the component used to draw the images...

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Many of the these [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a992484%20javax.swing.Timer) include illustrations, making it easy to select an interesting one for study.

Comment: @trashgod That saves me having to type it all in ;)